# Workbench SELECT statement error:SELECT IS NOT VALID AT THIS POSITION

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

can someone point out what mistake I am making.It gives following error.

> SELECT IS NOT VALID AT THIS POSITION FOR THIS SERVER VERSION

```
SELECT (CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS fullName),
        DATE_FORMAT(last_update,'%m%d%y') AS LastUpdated,
FROM sakila.actor;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have unwanted parentheses around the first expression in the `SELECT` clause (that wrongly include the column alias), and a trailing comma before `FROM`.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS fullName, 
    DATE_FORMAT(last_update, '%m%d%y') AS LastUpdated
FROM sakila.actor;
```